# Establishing Data-Binding in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I'm finding it **challenging to get data-binding working** for my sample WPF application in the MVVM style.

## Question:

What's missing in the following sample?

---

## Details:

### Basic Structure:

**Model:** `Customer` (doesn't matter actually)

**ViewModel:** `AllCustomersViewModel`

**View:** `WizardWindowView`

### Structural elements:

**Exposed by VM:** `AllCustomers` (of type ObservableCollection)

**Displayed on View:** `ListView`

**Want Binding:** `ListView <-> AllCustomers`

---

### WizardWindowView.xaml:

```
<Window 
    ...
    ...
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CustomerGroups" Source="{Binding Path=AllCustomers}"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    
    <Grid>
            ...
            ...
            <aw:WizardPage Header="Step 1">
                <ListView
                   ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CustomerGroups}}"/>
            </aw:WizardPage>
            ...
            ...
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

*I've already spent more than 10 hours trying to understand how data-binding is accomplished and feel it's time to ask for help!*

---

### EDIT

### Model info:

**Data:** `customers.xml`

**Model:** `Customer.cs`

**Data Access:** `CustomerRepository.cs`

### AllCustomersViewModel:

```
readonly CustomerRepository _customerRepository;
public AllCustomersViewModel(CustomerRepository customerRespository) {...}
```

---

### EDIT 2

Sequence of calls:

```
App.xaml.cs.OnStartup() {.. new MainWindowViewModel("Data/customers.xml")..};

public MainWindowViewModel(string customerDataFile)
{
    _customerRepository = new CustomerRepository(customerDataFile);
    new AllCustomersViewModel(_customerRepository);
}
```

---

### EDIT 3

### DataContext:

In App.xaml.cs:

```
    MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
    string path = "Data/customers.xml";
    var viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel(path);
    window.DataContext = viewModel;
```

In MainWindow.xaml.cs (the codebehind):

```
private void ShowWizardWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Views.WizardWindowView wizardWindow = new Views.WizardWindowView();
    wizardWindow.DataContext = this.DataContext;
    wizardWindow.Show();
}
```

Comment: Where and how do you set the DataContext? Have you tried `<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CustomerGroups}}"/>`? You can check the Output window in Visual Studio during runtime looking for binding errors.

Comment: @nemesv Thanks for the suggestion. I see that I have to bind my target to the source `CustomerGroups` which I hadn't done before. I just tried what you said with **no luck** though.

Comment: Are there any binding errors in the output window? It would be still interesting to know where do you set the `DataContext` of the `WizardWindowView`.

Comment: There are no errors. It's just a blank window. About the `DataContext`, I guess line 5 of the snippet in the question is setting it?

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if it's something to do with instantiating my data source (in case you see nothing wrong with the above snippet). See the edit in the question for the data instantiation.

Comment: Can we get some code for your View Model Class?

Comment: Tried instantiating, but looks like I'm not doing that right. The code's been updated.

Comment: I'm wondering how I should use the newly created instance of `AllCustomersViewModel`. It exposes the `AllCustomers` collection that the `WizardWindowView` uses for binding to the `ListView`.

Comment: @maelstrom3, I'm pretty sure you didn't set the DataContext... Did you read a tutorial about MVVM? I don't think you would have spent 10 hours on this problem if you had...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I meant I spent more than 10 hours reading various tutorials :) You are probably right that I didn't set the DataContext. Will try that out and reply once I get back to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After assistance from several people here, from my colleague and finally from some reading, I managed to establish data-binding! Actually, a simplified one compared to what I was originally hoping.

Sorry, my answer might not be the most organized, but I'm sure it'll be understandable.

---

### Accomplished

Displaying names of customers.

### Here's how

I have a `WizardWindowView` (similar to a WPF Window) on which I wanted to display the names of customers. `WizardPage` is a window (again, similar to a WPF Window) among several windows in the wizard. I also have the data-context set as in the question's edit section.

**Where are the names of the customers originally coming from?**
I have a data source which is an `xml` file. I also have a `AllCustomersViewModel.cs` class that gives an abstraction for the data in the xml file. If you want to know how the abstraction is done, you might have to do some reading on WPF! The abstraction is a collection of `CustomerViewModel` objects.

**Now, what are these `CustomerViewModel` objects?**
If `AllCustomersViewModel` abstracts the collection of customer data in the original xml file, `CustomerViewModel` abstracts each customer in the collection.

**What is the abstraction like or what is its type?**
`CustomerViewModel` exposes (this is `.net` jargon) a property called `FirstName` of type `string`. `AllCustomersViewModel` exposes a property called `AllCustomers` of type `ObservableCollection<CustomerViewModel>`.

**Now that I have the data to be displayed, I'm switching my focus to the `View (xaml)`:**
I'm trying to display the first names of the customers on my `WizardWindowView`.

Since I have to display a list and not just one or two elements in the list, I need a xaml control to display a list (`ListView`).

**What should the source for `ListView` be?**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllCustomers}">
```

To display each item in the list, I do the following:

```
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

---

**Summary:**

```
<aw:WizardPage Header="Step 3: Edit/Check Engine (Faulty Customers)">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllCustomers}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</aw:WizardPage>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Code-behind for the view you need to set the DataContext = ViewModel
public WizardWindowView() { ... DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel(); ... }
or in OnStartup() { App.MainWindow.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel(); }
Setting Window's DataContext is your missing piece.

Comment: I now have the `DataContext` set for `WizardWindowView`. See the edit in the question.